# Prove or disprove: If $n^3$ is odd then $n$ is odd.

Tags: proof-writing, arithmetic, examples-counterexamples

If $n^3$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.

I need to prove or disprove by means of counterexample why this is true or false.

$\forall x P(x) = x^3$, $x = 1,3,5,7,9$

I am having a very difficult time finding a way to prove this by counterexample!

Comment: If there's a counter example, then it isn't true.

Comment: Consider proving the contrapositive.

Comment: if $n$ isn't odd, then $n$ is even, therefore its third power is even, contradiction.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question does not specify whether or not n is an integer.

Comment: When we speak of odd and even numbers, we mean integers.

Comment: You need to be aware that there is no such thing as proving by counterexample.  One can only disprove a statement by counterexample.

Comment: @SageHopkins Then it's a wrong statement. $\left(\sqrt[3]{3}\right)^3$ is odd, but $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is not odd (because it's not an integer).

Comment: Do not leave $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @AlvinLepik Yes, but if $n^3$ is an integer, then $n$ doesn't have to be an integer.

Comment: You can only prove falsity with a counterexample, not truth. And "we found no counterexample" is no valid argument.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is just a poorly written question. I think $n, n^3\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It absolutely *MUST* be stated in the premise *somewere* that $n \in \mathbb N$ if we are to assume so.  I must definitely would say $n^3 = 3$ *is* a counterexample.

Comment: That logical proposition isn't correctly stated by the way.

Comment: @fleablood: I find your insistence on this technical point very strange. Yes, the question could be less ambiguous. But there is an interpretation which makes the question interesting, and there is an interpretation that makes the question boring. I'm not sure why you insist on giving both equal weight. If I asked my students in an intro to proof course this exact statement, I would expect them to give a proof in the integral case, and to make a small note at the beginning saying "by the way Eric, you screwed up the question: we should assume $n$ is an integer."

Comment: I'm insistent because math is about definitions and not making assumptions.  The question probably does state that $n$ is a natural number (otherwise it wouldn't use the variable "n" and it probably would have wouldn't have said n is just "odd" but "an odd integer").  But *very* soon and *frequently* the OP is going to come across situations where specifications matter.  Not all sequences have limits.  Not all numbers are rational.  Not all functions are continuous or defined everywhere.    And the statement "all numbers" is *excedingly* unclear. Clarity and specifics do matter.

Comment: "But there is an interpretation which makes the question interesting, and there is an interpretation that makes the question boring."  That's your opinion.  I think the exact opposite.  n an integer so n^3 odd => n odd is, to me, very boring and obvious and easy.  But n^3 odd *not* implying that n is an integer I find *much* more interesting in that it illustrates assumptions and the nescessity of clarity is specifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $n^3$ is odd, but $n$ is not odd. Then $n$ must be even. The product of any two even numbers is even, so $n^2$ is even. Then $n(n^2)=n^3$ is the product of two even numbers again: and so $n(n^2)=n^3$ is even. This contradicts the assumption that $n^3$ is odd, and so $n$ is not even. So $n$ must be odd.

Answer (score 2):

If $n^3$ is odd,
then
$n^3 = 2m+1$
for some $m$.

Therefore
$2m 
= n^3-1
=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)
$.

$n^2+n+1$
is odd,
since
$n^2+n = n(n+1)$
is even,
being the product
of two consecutive integers.

But $2m$ is even,
so
$n-1$ is even,
since the product
of two odd numbers is odd.

Therefore
$n$ is odd.

Answer (score -1):

- if $n$ is even, $n^3$ is even.
- if $n$ is odd, $n^3$ is odd.

Therefore $n$ is odd iff $n^3$ is odd.

Answer (score -1):

You can never prove anything by showing a counter-example.  If you can find a counter example then the statement is not true.

Now this is *VERY*  *VERY* **VERY** important.  **WHAT** is the *exact* wording of the problem?  Does it, or does it not, *specifically* state that $n$ must be a natural number?

The answer are **COMPLETELY** different depending on whether $n$ is assumed to be a natural number or not.

1)  $n$ need not be a natural number:

This is tricky because if $n$ is odd, then $n^3$ is odd.  But the converse, if $n^3$ is odd implies $n$ is odd, is only true if $n$ is an integer... or in other words if $n^3$ is not a perfect cube then $n$ is not an integer and $n$ is neither even nor odd.

So counter examples are $n^3 = 3,5,7,9,11,13,,15,...25,29,.... $ etc.

Now... *IF* the problem specifies that $n$ must be a *natural number*.  Then those are *not* counter examples because $n^3 = 3 \iff n = \sqrt[3]3 \not \in \mathbb N$.

2))

$n \in \mathbb N$

Either $n$ is odd and $n = 2k + 1$ for some $k \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$.  Or $n$ is even and $n=2k$ for  $k \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$.  If $n = 2k$ is even, then $n^3 = (2k)^3 = 8k^3 = 2*(4k^3)$ is even.  So if $n^3$ is odd, $n$ can not be even.  So $n$ must be odd.